# what MySQL permissions are required for mysql_real_escape_string()?

Tags: php, mysql

what MySQL permissions are required for `mysql_real_escape_string()`?

i want to create a db user with the minimum abilities specifically for using with mres()...

Comment: Did you encounter any problem doing this? because it should go ok.

Comment: You must be connected to mysql " mysql_connect() " before calling mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: @ Codler, agree, otherwise you can use addshashes().

Comment: Except `addslashes()` doesn't take into account the server version and what special characters it needs escaped.  That's why we even have a `mysql_real_escape_string()` function...  And of course it needs to be connected, but the question was what permissions were needed (if you need `execute` permissions as if it was a SP or a function, etc)...

Comment: the question is quite a nonsense. why do you need to use mres? why not to use adddslashes? why do you need such a user?

Comment: @ col shrapnel - http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string but PDO is still more important

Comment: @Haroldo sorry pal you didn't get the question. read it again. with no SELECT or edit ability this function is useless. it have sense only in the **SAME CONNECTION** with following operation. othervise it's as useless as addslashes. why you all never think but just repeat mechanically what you learned here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's done on the client side, so the only permission needed is usage (since all you need is a connection, not even read permissions)...

Comment: The **USAGE** permission stands for "No Privileges" mainly in MySQL.

Comment: Actually no.  `Usage` allows you to log in and select the database.  You can't do anything else, but you can get access.  And since `mysql_real_escape_string` only requires a connection, all you need is access.  So yes, `USAGE` is sufficient for `mysql_real_escape_string`.  Sure, you can't do anything else, but you can do what the original question was...

Comment: and nobody wondered why such a question. I wish there was a habit on SO, kind of tradition.. to think at least once per 10 answers...

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT, after comments of "ircmaxell"**:-
You will require the following permissions / privileges to be set:-

1. INSERT
2. SELECT
3. UPDATE
4. CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES

The above privileges are the minimum ones that should be provided to any user account of each & every database of MySQL.

If administrator wants to create just a basic simple account, where the user will need to view / select the records, then only the "**SELECT**" permission is just required. No other permissions are needed to be given *(as regards to the comment of "ircmaxell")*.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Never add `ALTER` or `INDEX` permissions for a production account.  If you application modifies tables dynamically, you **really** need to rethink the problem... Only administrators (And internal administration applications) should have those two permissions...

Comment: @ircmaxell - Thanks for the info, I'm changing my answer accordingly.

Comment: Removed -1...  Otherwise that is a good baseline of permissions (depending on need of course.  You may want some accounts to only have `SELECT`)...